# How to do conditional count in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

Assume in Status column their has values present, absent. I want to count how many present or how many absent has their. In Bi publisher(rtf) How can we do that ? Whats the code I need to write in MS Word ?
I tried some code like `<?if:Status='Present'>Count of 'Present': <?count(current-group()/Status[@value='Present'])?><?end if?>`  but it don't work. gives error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sv6V.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRw3y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
<?if:Status='Present'>
```

Should be

```
<?if:Status='Present'?>
```